# Работа с ViewControllerАми

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Здравствуйте, не знаю как лучше сформировать заголовок, так что ниже постараюсь по подробнее описать суть проблемы. Но скажу сразу что **знаю** что так лучше не делать, что это плохой тон, что так писать нельзя, но поверьте нет другого выбора.

Есть страничка в сторибоарде(ViewController). В него я добавляю еще один ViewController

```
    myVC = [[myViewController alloc] init];
    myVC.delegate = self;
    myVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(362, 125, 300, 560);
    myVC.view.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myVC.view];
```

З.Ы. UI myViewControllera в ксибе.

ну и если кнопочку нажать вылазит это вью, в нем табличка.

Скрин
http://uaimage.com/t/3538726_ddced270.jpg

как вы заметили в табличке есть Disclosure Indicator

хочу по нажатию на ячейку показывать на месте myViewControllera другую страничку с инфой про то что было в ячейке.

Идеально было бы юзать NavigationController но что-то не так..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:dvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ничего не происходит, DetailViewController так же с ЮИ в ксибе. Я пробовал кодом создавать NavigationBar, но что я ему не говорил он ничем мне не помогал, думаю просто мне опыта не хватает т.к. в Objective C я пару месяцев. Получается я в первом вью объявил второе и во втором хочу вызвать третье, ех. Ну меня получалось вызывать третье во втором но оно вызалило за экран первого вью. Короче это ужас какой-то.

И того, хотелось бы что б при нажатии на ячейку вылетала страничка DetailViewController перекрывая страничку с таблицей(как на мобильных за частую), и через NavigationBar возвращаться назад. Если это не возможно то буду рад выслушать предложения как выйти из положения, но надо еще одну страничку вывести. Всем спасибо.

Comment: о_О В навигатор контроллер пушат и попять другие контроллеры...

Answer (score 1):

Инициализация `UITableViewController` как `UINavigationController`

`UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];`

Переход на другой `ViewController`

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}`

Комбинация различных видов контроллеров:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tableViewController];    
    /* объявляем какие-угодно контроллеры для UITabBarController */  
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                             navigationController,
                                             /*перечисляем все остальные контроллерв*/
                                             nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    return YES;
}`

Comment: Советую как можно раньше отказаться от ксибов и сторибоардов, на реальных проектах будете постоянно отгребать проблемы из-за них

Comment: @Алексей Алыбин Инициализацию мне писать в первом вьюКонтроллере или во втором во вьюДидЛоад?

Я просто думал что бы вобще второй убрать, ибо в нем только таблица, ее впихнуть в первый, может так бы лучше было.

да я их не люблю особо ксибы и сторибоарды, это старый проект дали дописать, с нуля переписывать нет желания, вот и парусь с ними

Comment: У вас будет только 2 контроллера - таблица и детальный просмотр. Инициализацию делать в `AppDelegate.m` и назначить его рутовым контроллером `self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;`

Comment: PS: инициализацию чего-либо всегда нужно делать в методе `init` а не в вьюДидЛоад

Comment: @Алексей Алыбин Если я не ошибаюсь, то AppDeledate мне для всего приложения применит навигейшн контроллер, мне так нельзя, у меня TabBarController всем заведует. Про инит спасибо, буду знать :)

Comment: @Рома Сименок Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

советую все собрать в storyboard и выставить все связи, можно вообще не прибегать в написанию кода и свести это дело на минимум